# What to call a meeting with boss/colleague?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

"I have to hurry - I have a meeting with my boss at 2pm."

> Je dois me dépêcher - j'ai ____ avec ma chef à 2 heures de l'après-midi.

What should the translation of "meeting" be? If it's a group meeting at work I think it's *une réunion*; if it's a meeting with a friend I think it's *un rendez-vous*. But in this case it's an individual meeting with a boss.

Same question if "boss" is replaced by "colleague".

> Je dois me dépêcher - j'ai ____ avec mon collègue à 2 heures de l'après-midi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *rendez-vous* is not restricted to dates with friends so might be used in both cases.

Comment: What about *réunion*? Is it appropriate here as well? Or *rencontre*?

Comment: Yes, *j'ai une réunion* might also be used even when there are only two persons in the meeting.

Comment: Is there a difference between *réunion* and *rendez-vous*, or are the two exactly the same in this context? (Sorry for asking many questions.)

Comment: There is a slight difference while in that case, it is dim. A *rendez-vous* is the precise time and location where people (or whatever) planned to meet together, a *réunion* is an event where people meet together.

Answer (score 2):

Si on veut mettre l'accent sur le caractère obligatoire de la réunion et sur le lien de subordination, on peut dire:

> Je suis convoqué par ma chef à 14h.

Answer (score 1):

If it is an individual meeting with a boss:

> un entretien

If it is an individual meeting with a colleague:

> une entrevue

Note that `un rendez-vous` is more broad and works for both.